#  Jquery select second cell in table

Tags: jquery

This is the code on the script, i need to get the content from the second cell.
The table hasnt got a id but is in a div with the id 'Chat'

The 4th row i can select:

```
var row = $("#chat tr:nth-child(4)");
```

But not the second cell:

```
var cellContent = $("#chat td:nth-child(4)").html();
```

I cant post images or table tags, so this is a link to the image of the table and its code.
http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/8871/chattable.png

Comment: Here's a JSfiddle with your Jquery question's HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/CrumK/

Comment: I highly recommend you split these questions apart.

Comment: GREAT you split them!  Don't forget to accept the answer that works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that hopefully helps your jquery question. http://jsfiddle.net/CrumK/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // this reads: find the element with ID chat and inside that find every TR element that is the 2nd child of its parent (meaning TABLE).
    $("#chat tr:nth-child(2)").css("color", "blue");  // select the second row

    // this reads: find the element with ID chat and inside that find every TD element that is the 2nd child of its parent (meaning TR)    
    $("#chat td:nth-child(2)").css("background", "red"); // select every second TD

    // select the second TD of the second TR inside the #chat element
    $("#chat tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").css("background", "green");  // select the second row
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Kasdega, that solved the Jquery question

**$("#chat td:nth-child(5)").each(function() {alert($(this).html());} );**


Now the hardest one, the setInterval Hijack

Comment: Sorry can't help ya with that one.  One reason to split them apart.

Comment: Since you have an answer here for the jquery, I'd take your greasmonkey question and remove it from here and ask it as another question.  Then you can accept this answer and still get help on the other part.